# count distinct users in pbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a list of tasks to be completed by users.  I can calculate the

```
# of task incompleted Incompletions = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('DB Task'),
    'DB Task'[Status]="Incomplete"
)+0
```

How can I get the number of distinct users ?   In my example, it would be 4 incompleted tasks from 2 distinct users.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D08YC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this below-

```
# of distinct user = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Name'),
    'DB Task'[Status]="Incomplete"
)+0
```

Comment: @Cookie nice to see it worked. You can also put an upvote to the answer :)

Comment: is it possible to extract from the model and create a separate table for a distinct list of the tasks with two columns displaying the count of completed and incomplete status for each of the task   i.e. col 1 distinct list of tasks; col 2 count of status = complete ; col 3 count of status = incomplete

Comment: Yes, possible. You can post another question this case. With sample data and your expected output.

Comment: posted another question, hope you can share knowledge how this can be done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203024/create-table-from-pbi-dataset-distinct-count-and-separate-field-counts