# create table from PBI dataset - distinct count and separate field counts

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with a set of tasks, tasker and status in a PBI dataset.  how can I create a separate table from this data to a set of distinct tasks with counts of taskers and status in separate columns.  [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS4qb.png)

Tried potential solution but ended up with an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTS2P.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can do it using **DAX**, I would prefer to do it in **Power Query Editor** using **M**. Just create a new table using the below **Advance Editor** code.

**Note**: Change the **source_table_name** with your original table name.

```
let
    Source = source_table_name,
    #"Grouped Rows" = 
        Table.Group(
                Source, 
                {"Task"}, 
                {
                    {"count of tasker id", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, 
                    {"status = completed", 
                        each Table.RowCount(
                            Table.SelectRows(_,each [Status] = "completed")
                        ), Int64.Type
                    }, 
                    {"status = incomplete", 
                        each Table.RowCount(
                            Table.SelectRows(_,each [Status] = "incomplete")
                        ), Int64.Type
                    }
                }
            )
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: took me quite some time to find out how to do this, but ended up with Expression.Error: the import DB_Task matches no exports.  Did you miss a module reference?    Don't know why it is not recognizing the table when it's is there.

Comment: show me the code and error (image upload to https://imgur.com/)

Comment: Screen shot added to original question above

Comment: Hi @Cookie I can see your table name is [DB Task], why you use DB_Task?

Comment: I got syntax error when I put DB Task,  if I put a DB_Task, I get through

Comment: You have to write like>  Source = #"DB Task",

Comment: finally got that working, so correct me if I am wrong... if there is space in the table name, need to express in Source = #"table name", otherwise it would be just Source = source_table_name .     thanks for being patient with a rookie.

Comment: @Cookie you are right :) You can also put an upvote to increase my reputation :)

Comment: @ mkRabbani , I wanted to put an upvote, but wasn't allowed until I reached 15 (I am really new).  will certainly do that when I finally reach that status :)

Comment: @Cookie you are above 15 now ;)